# What does "error code 13" mean in the Node package Request?

Tags: node.js, express, requestjs

I'm using a node server that uses Request to hit a different server. The servers are in the same internal environment and have no connection restrictions, such as firewall or auth. However, whenever I try send a POST request from one to another, I get this error from Request.js:

```
    Request resp: {
       "pathname": "/testSocket",
       "path": "/testSocket",
       "body": "There was a problem with your request. Error code 13",
       "href": "{hidden for privacy}"

    Request body: "There was a problem with your request. Error code 13"
```

Does anyone know what Error Code 13 means in this context? I can't find any Node, Express, or Request documentation that explains it.

Comment: What about your request options, can you please include those in your question?

Comment: Just an observation - it looks like the problem is reported by this "different server" you mentioned. You received proper response (you should have also statusCode field there, most likely with value 500 or 400). If the problem had occurred in request.js itself, most likely you would got Error without body/response fields.

Comment: This intended server must be returning this response.Can you give a little bit info on what is happening after the request reaches the different server?Is it accessing any database or such?